# Bind Server on Azure to solve reverse DNS issue

Tags: azure, dns, centos, bind, reverse-dns

I've currently run into an issue withe the Azure platform.  It seems that they do not provide reverse DNS and support for it is not coming for a while it seems.  I've been trying to setup a BIND DNS server on my box so that I can get reverse DNS enabled.  I'm new to BIND and I've been having issues getting it to work properly, but I wanted to check to see if this is a plausible way to get Reverse DNS working on these Azure VMs.

Thanks
Chris

Answer (score 1):

It's currently not possible to set PTR records on Windows Azure even if you set up your own BIND Server because you have no rights to manipulate the reverse records of that IP address.
This is only possible if you are the owner of the IP-Subnet or if the Subnet owner permits you.

Comment: and in the case of Windows Azure the owner of IP Address/Range is Microsoft. PTR support is currently the most wanted feature. Give your votes here: http://feedback.windowsazure.com/forums/34192-general-feedback-/suggestions/3090834-provide-reverse-dns-ptr-records-for-virtual-mach to help it become feature of Windows Azure!

Answer (score 0):

Azure Reverse DNS now Possible

http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/21/announcing-reverse-dns-for-azure-cloud-services/